# Cordova select and upload image

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I have a jqm+phonegap application running on cordova 2.9.0 for ios platform.

On android, the following code worked, but it isn't working on iOS...

JS:

```
function getImage() {

navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
alert('Get Picture Failed. Please Try Again.');
},{
quality: 50,
destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
}
);

}

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey="file";
options.fileName=curClub+imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

var params = new Object();
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";
params.clubID = curClub ;
options.params = params;
options.chunkedMode = false;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(imageURI, "url", win, fail, options);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role = "button" onClick = "getImage();" >Upload Logo</div>
```

If i test the getImage() function by adding an alert inside, it works, so i know that it is going there. What else am I doing wrong?

Comment: Witch is the problem? the phone take the image?

Comment: No, nothing happens when I click the button which is supposed to take it to the getImage() function

Comment: Have you added the permission for the camera?